# Error 404 on the homepage of wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, ssl, http-status-code-404

my website www.auzcan.com 's homepage is showing 404 error, however other pages are working fine after installation of SSL certificates from GoDaddy. I've tried every solution available here but all in vain. Looking forward for help from your end. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Too many possibilities to guess without your configuration, enviroment info etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking what your front page is set to in Admin panel-> Settings-> Reading.

It should either have the your latest posts option selected, or the static page option selected and the front page set to a valid page.

it might be a case of not having a home page set correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and the solution for me was to add these lines to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf`, which is my SSL-enabled website's configuration file:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Of course, this assumes DocumentRoot `/var/www/html`. Change accordingly if is this is different in your setup.

The thing is that Wordpress uses **.htaccess** rules to process the URLs and for them to work, **AllowOverride** **All** needs to be in the server's configuration file.

In my situation, the configuration for the non-SSL and SSL-enabled variants were in a separate files. The non-SSL configuration had **AllowOverride All** all along, and so everything was working fine. Once I had enabled the SSL, the other configuration file came into play and didn't have the required **AllowOverride All** setting.